# Is my main-panel's neutral currently bonded to ground?

Tags: wiring

[image]Good Day, 
I am installing a sub panel in a detached workshop. I have seen that in the main panel that my neutral should be bonded to the ground in the main panel and not in the sub panel. Looking at my main panel, I cannot tell if the neutral is bonded or not. If it is not, does this change the way I hook up the sub panel? Pic is attached, can anyone tell if they are bonded? Thank You!

Added image of entire panel and this is the only service panel. 
[image]
[image]

From the look of this diagram it seems to me that it is not bonded. I am also looking into google.

[image]

[image]

On the lack of ground wires... it is the braided mess coming out of the hole at the bottom. This is a 40 year old home so all the ground wires are small and were originally braided together when they came out of the wall into the original fuse box.

[image]

[image]

Here are the grounds coming from the house as you request.

I have been out of town on work and not able to do any more with this. I do have a bonding the screw to use. Also, just found out the electrician that has not returned my call is in the hospital, so not a good time to talk to him. I can post more pics if I get the chance to work with it this week. Right above this box is the meter, is there a possibility of it being bonded there?

As far as the directory, I haven't gone through the switches to see what's what yet. I intended to do that right after the install, but got rained out. So I don't have a directory just yet.

Comment: It would help if you also provided a wider shot. The N-G bond is often on a strip that is below the break block. Also, do you have another service panel between the meter and this one? It's common to have a shutoff panel and the N-G bond can be made there.

Comment: I cannot see a N-G bond. As I understand it, in modern panels there is a "green screw" which makes this bond and I don't see one. Would this screw go into that metal contact in the center, top between the two protruding bars (ends of the bus bars?)? What is the purpose of having two wire clamps on the neutral (left) side?

Comment: It could be that in this panel the green screw for N-G bonding is supposed to go in the hole where the neutral bar is electrically and mechanically connected to the incoming neutral connection block. The green screw would be longer than an unmarked screw so that the (self tapping) green screw would  into a hole in the panel and so connect the neutral to the metal panel. The ground bar is already connected to the panel.

Comment: Thank You Jim for the information. Could the little green screw next on the top right be the bonding screw? Its a bit hard to see. I will take a closer look at it when I get home.

Comment: I saw a little green spot next to the ground connection (upper right) and wondered what that was. I now see that this is a green screw that is obscured by the hot line above it. It could be that is a hole where the bonding screw is stowed but in that location it does make a N-G bond, or it might be making a bond. You really need the instructions for this particular panel.

Comment: Is the panel in the pictures the existing main panel? If it is, then some of the things I have said in comments might not apply. If this is the main panel and you can see the green screw, then maybe the green screw *is* bonding the N to G. I think that the panels come with the bond in place and it is up to the installer to remove the bond if the panel is being used as a sub-panel. **I wish one of the experts would chime in because I am not comfortable with giving advice on connections in a main panel.** It could be that the green screw must be on top of the neutral bar to make a N-G bond.

Comment: Google for the instructions for this model of electrical panel.

Comment: This is the existing main panel. Just installed about 3 weeks ago and electrician hasn’t returned my calls. There is the large solid copper wire that runs up to the meter. Could it be bonded there from what I’ve read it should be bonded in the box.

Comment: I don’t want to move forward and connect my sub panel until I know for sure what I need to do.

Comment: Look on the sticker on the door of the panel and give us the mfgr and model number of this panel. The sticker has some instructions on installation and may state where the green screw is supposed to be placed for bonding. Where in the world is this?

Comment: Can you post photos that show the area under the topmost neutral and ground lugs clearly? We can't see them in the existing photos due to the top row of breakers being in the way

Comment: If you have a VOM use it on a resistance scale and check the resistance between the neutral bar and the ground bar. If they are bonded, then you will get at most 1 ohm and probably a lot less like maybe 0.05 ohm. (I didn't think of this at first because of your title. I though the pics were of your new sub-panel. you should edit the title to change "sub-panel's" to main panel's).

Comment: Can you provide some more photos of that ground bundle, as well as how the wires coming into the panel from the service are routed? I think there's something bigger going on here...

Comment: @GLJones77 -- can you post a photo of the panel's directory/circuit-labeling, as well as the wires landing on the breakers below the 40A breaker, and the red and black wires going into the left side breakers?  Also, what's the nameplate rating on the appliance powered by that 40A breaker, and how big (in square feet) is your house?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the 2-pole main breaker is in this panel makes it unlikely that the neutral and ground are bonded elsewhere. There is a simple and direct way to determine this: Use an ohmmeter to measure the resistance between the neutral and the ground. I suppose if they are not bonded, then there could be a potential difference between the two so it might be prudent to first put the multimeter in the voltage mode and change to ohm mode (resistance mode) if there is no significant voltage difference. However, modern multimeters probably are NOT easily damaged in the resistance mode. I don't think you would need to cut power to the house (by switching off the main 2-pole breaker) to make this measurement, but one of the experts here might have a contrary opinion.

You could also bond the neutral and ground by connecting them with a heavy wire. #10 would probably be sufficient, but it might need to be heavier. It is probably the case that since this is not the prescribed bonding method for this panel you should only bond with the correct green screw (diameter and length) in the hole indicated in the instructions. That screw should have come with the panel. It could be that the installing electrician took it out instead of tightening it down to make the bond.

Our house has a GE panel (but much older model) which takes the 1/2" breakers like this one, and **I want to alert you to something**. I do not know how you will feed the sub-panel from this main panel. I assume you will use a 2-pole breaker (30 A or 40 A or 50 A ?) and will probably want to use the type which is 2 x 1/2" (THQP230 or THQP240 or THQP250). These 2-pole breakers **will not fit in just any adjacent pair of 1/2" slots**, but only those pairs of 1/2" slots where one slot is on one 120-V leg and the other slot is on the other 120-V leg.

For example, I am sure that the two 1/2" slots in position 1 of your panel will not accept a  THQP 2-pole breaker, but you will be able to put a THQP 2-pole breaker in the lower slot of position 1 and the upper slot of position 3. Both the breaker and the panel have projections which prevent a breaker from snapping in if the two 1/2" slots are on the same leg.

I speak from experience because I (ignorantly) tried to put in a 50-A 2-pole breaker without realizing this. It looked like it would fit, but it would not snap in. I used considerable force, and was about to get out a hammer (you know just to *tap* it in), but a voice told me to stop and consider before I did any damage to my new 50-A 2-pole breaker or any damage to the panel. When I put the THQP250 in correctly it snapped right in.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the information. I broke down and had another electrician take a look at everything. Added a bonding screw to neutral, wired and hooked up the sub panel and I am now good to go. I was teetering on the edge to do it myself, but one thing I do not like to mess with is electricity. I just don't have the knowledge and this is a DIY job that has much potential to do harm if done improperly.

Comment: So did the electrician wire the sub-panel through a 2-pole breaker and if so what size? Did he use a THQP2 __ breaker (2 x 1/2") for the sub-panel or one of the larger (2 x 1") 2-pole breakers? How many of the existing circuits in the main panel were moved to the sub-panel?

Comment: 2 pole 50a breaker 2x1" No existing circuits moved.

Answer (score 2):

### The neutral and ground do not appear to be bonded

Take a closer look (and attach pictures for us) at the places I've circled in red below

[image: Bonding Screw Locations]

On the right, it appears there's a green screw. According to the drawing, this makes sense, as it serves to bond the enclosure to the ground. It's marked on the drawings as "Bonded." It likely came from the factory like this.

On the left, there appears to be a hole for a bonding screw, but no screw is present. Accordingly, the drawing marks it as "Bond when required." To me, this indicates that the panel can be used as a main service panel when a screw is threaded through the hole in the lug and makes good electrical contact with the enclosure metal. Without this screw, the neutral and ground would be separate in this panel.

It also seems likely that they are not bonded because the there are no green or bare wires going to the left (neutral) busbar, and similarly, only green or bare wires seem to go to the right (ground) busbar.

Unrelated, but I am confused by the utter lack of ground wires anywhere, except the one going off into the knockout on the right and the large, twisted bundle. Do you know what kind of wiring you have in your house? Is everything in conduit or on metallic-clad cables? I'm just curious.

Comment: The detail photo of the left side lugs confirms your suspicion that this panel lacks a bond.

Comment: So do I bond this myself by connecting the neutral and ground? What are the consequences of going forward with hooking up the sub panel without this bond?

Comment: Is this main panel in use? If it is in use without a low resistance, high current capacity N-G bond it place, then it is not safe.  The breaker might not trip in the event of an energized ground.  Before proceeding test for a bond. Go to an electrical supply and get a proper length green bonding screw for this panel. Do you have a VOM or equivalent. They are not expensive. Even a basic Fluke is not expensive and is reliable.

Comment: Yes, this is the main panel in use. I have all the wires run to my sub panel in my workshop, nothing is hooked up yet. I am not going to proceed until it is safe. I am heading to the store now.

Comment: I agree this panel does not have N-G bond (no screw near upper left lug). But that does not mean N and G are unbonded in your installation. Is there any other service panel between this one and your meter? If so the bond occurs there. Either way, going back to your original question how to ground a detached workshop depends how far it is from this panel and what wires you are running to service it. Will prob require a separate question to answer. Or better yet search for t because it’s been asked and answered before.

Comment: @GLJones77 So that ground braid *wasn't* just a larger gauge bundle but a bundle of individual ground wires. How interesting. Thanks for indulging my curiosity!

Comment: If you already have purchased the sub-panel, you could remove the green N-G bonding screw from the sub-panel (where it won't be needed) and install it in the main panel. Just be sure it is long enough for the main panel.

Answer (score 1):

### If you can't find that screw...

If you can't find the bonding screw that goes to your panel, order GE part number TBS from your local electrical supply house -- that's the official bonding screw kit GE offers for most of their PowerMark Gold line.

### Fix those handle-tie hijinks while you're in there

It looks like there's a MWBC (black and red wire pair on the left side of the panel) that's missing it's handle tie (GE part number THT1), and the handle ties on the right side of the panel are improper as well -- you'll need a THT1 or two (I suspect the handle tie on the far bottom right breakers is superfluous) and a THT2 to address that.  (Post more detailed photos of the wiring and directory, and I can address this more definitively.)